# Error Occuring during module upgrade in Openerp

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I am new in openerp. I have created a new module, it was successfully installed and everything works fine. But when I try to upgrade the module I got an error like this:

```
> 2013-05-09 14:59:45,117 7236 ←[1;31m←[1;49mERROR←[0m Fisc openerp.osv.osv: Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 121, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 176, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 164, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 456, in button_immediate_upgra
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_upgrade, context=context)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 418, in _button_immediate_func
    _, pool = pooler.restart_pool(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.new(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module, True)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 176, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 333, in load_modules
    processed = load_marked_modules(cr, graph, states_to_load, force, status, report, loaded_modules)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 244, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 179, in load_module_graph
    load_update_xml(module_name, idref, mode)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 76, in <lambda>
    load_update_xml = lambda *args: _load_data(cr, *args, kind='update_xml')
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 119, in _load_data
    tools.convert_csv_import(cr, module_name, pathname, fp.read(), idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 931, in convert_csv_import
    raise Exception(_('Module loading failed: file %s/%s could not be processed:\n %s') % (module, fname, warning_msg))
Exception: Module loading failed: file crm_livechat/crm_livechat\security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
 Line 1 : No matching record found for external id 'crm.group_crm_user' in field 'Group'
2013-05-09 14:59:45,134 7236 ←[1;31m←[1;49mERROR←[0m Fisc openerp.netsvc: Module loading failed: file crm_livechat/crm_
 Line 1 : No matching record found for external id 'crm.group_crm_user' in field 'Group'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\netsvc.py", line 361, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 585, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 167, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 121, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 176, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 164, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 456, in button_immediate_upgra
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_upgrade, context=context)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 418, in _button_immediate_func
    _, pool = pooler.restart_pool(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.new(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module, True)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 176, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 333, in load_modules
    processed = load_marked_modules(cr, graph, states_to_load, force, status, report, loaded_modules)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 244, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 179, in load_module_graph
    load_update_xml(module_name, idref, mode)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 76, in <lambda>
    load_update_xml = lambda *args: _load_data(cr, *args, kind='update_xml')
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 119, in _load_data
    tools.convert_csv_import(cr, module_name, pathname, fp.read(), idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 931, in convert_csv_import
    raise Exception(_('Module loading failed: file %s/%s could not be processed:\n %s') % (module, fname, warning_msg))
Exception: Module loading failed: file crm_livechat/crm_livechat\security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
 Line 1 : No matching record found for external id 'crm.group_crm_user' in field 'Group'
> c:\openerp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\tools\convert.py(931)convert_csv_import()
-> raise Exception(_('Module loading failed: file %s/%s could not be processed:\n %s') % (module, fname, warning_msg))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error show thats error comes from **crm_livechat** module from **security/ir.model.access.csv** file, it not find **crm.group_crm_user** such type of group.
Please check for this group it define or not, if you are using 7 or 6.1 then i think this group are removed already from crm,

Comment: I am using openerp7. SO what is the solution?

Comment: then replace **crm.group_crm_user** with **base.group_sale_salesman**